# Log Execution Failed Viewshed (line 266,351,888,163)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed, visibility

I found difficulties when doing viewsheed and network intervisibility. The steps I have taken are:

1. Download DEM from opentopograhy SRTM 30
2. Wrap projection DEM rasterized to UTM 84
3. The collection of coordinate points is saved on SHP using UTM instead of WGS 84

can someone explain what error is and how to fix this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/rekoa/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\algorithms\viewshed_raster.py", line 266, in processAlgorithm
matrix_vis = ws.viewshed_raster (analysis_type, pt[id1], dem,
File "C:\Users/rekoa/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\algorithms\modules\visibility.py", line 163, in viewshed_raster
dem.open_window (point["pix_coord"])
File "C:\Users/rekoa/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\algorithms\modules\Raster.py", line 351, in open_window
self.rst.ReadAsArray(*self.gdal_slice ).astype(float)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~2.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 3803, in ReadAsArray
from osgeo import gdal_array
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~2.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~2.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 13, in <module>
from . import _gdal_array
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~2.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Execution failed after 43.10 seconds
```

below is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe comma as a decimal separator makes confusion. Change the locale settings of your QGIS into something that is using points as separator and try again.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to place the error message in the Question body as text. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others with the same issue.

Comment: @user30184, it's not working.

Comment: Does `import numpy` work in QGIS' python console (Ctrl-Alt-P)?

Comment: @bugmenot123, not working

Comment: Afaik that seems like your QGIS installation is weird. Can you try reinstalling QGIS?